# Cannot stop logging of stacktrace with Camel ActiveMQ JMS

Tags: java, exception, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm using Camel 2.9.1 with Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE and ActiveMQ 5.5.1.

I have a Swing GUI client which is using Camel JMS to make `@InOut` request-reply calls to a data service which is running in a bundle in a Karaf/Felix OSGi container on our server.

This service, in certain circumstances, throws exceptions which we want to deal with in the client.

When these exceptions are thrown, Camel passes them back to the Client wrapped in a `RuntimeCamelException` and it all works fine.

But now I would like to suppress the stacktrace that Camel seems to log automatically when the Exception passes back to the client. Here's a snippet from the server's Log:

```
2012-11-01 13:04:13,463 | ERROR | org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-pc01-48122-1351720826468-9-121549 on ExchangeId: ID-pc01-48122-1351720826468-9-121547). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught:org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1221)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation.invoke(BeanInvocation.java:87)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:128)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
... etc.
```

which is immediately followed in the log with:

```
2012-11-01 13:04:13,517 | WARN  | org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger | Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1221)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation.invoke(BeanInvocation.java:87)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:128)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:115)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:285)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
...etc
```

Now the Spring file for the **Client** has the folowing definition:

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://${current.host}:${current.port}?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="requestTimeout" value="60000"/>
    <property name="transferException" value="true"/>
    <property name="errorHandlerLogStackTrace" value="false"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Which has the `errorHandlerLogStackTrace` property set to 'false', so I'm not sure why it's still logging the stacktraces.

Do I need to have a similar property setting on the server side (since this is the server log which contains the stacktraces)?

By the way, most of this stuff was set up by a previous employee who no longer works for us. Although I have a fairly good understanding of what's going on, some of it is still a mystery to me.

**UPDATE: 5/11/12 - After Claus's answer**

OK, I went digging a bit more through the Spring DSL XML files and found that the JMS Component was being defined on the server in a separate OSGi bundle called 'broker' which the other server bundles were referring to. This bundle had the same XML definition of the 'jms' bean as the client had (above).

I added the 'errorHandlerLogStackTrace' property to this definition and this has managed to get rid of one of the stack-traces. What I'm getting now is an ERROR with a stack-trace, followed immediately by a WARN without a stack-trace. Here's a more complete snippet:

```
2012-11-05 10:44:35,323 | ERROR | org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-pc01-38192-1352065125718-9-62 on ExchangeId: ID-pc01-38192-1352065125718-9-60). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1221)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation.invoke(BeanInvocation.java:87)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:128)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:115)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:285)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:333)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:223)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:104)[147:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)[63:org.springframework.jms:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here
    at uniworks.ServiceManagers.SuperDataManager.createInUseForEntity(SuperDataManager.java:2156)[220:uniworks-ejb:1.1.4.SNAPSHOT]
    at uniworks.ServiceManagers.SuperDataManager.findForEdit(SuperDataManager.java:913)[220:uniworks-ejb:1.1.4.SNAPSHOT]
    at uniworks.ServiceManagers.SuperDataManager.findForEdit(SuperDataManager.java:853)[220:uniworks-ejb:1.1.4.SNAPSHOT]
    at uniworks.ServiceManagers.SuperDataManager.findForEdit(SuperDataManager.java:843)[220:uniworks-ejb:1.1.4.SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_24]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)[65:org.springframework.transaction:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy221.findForEdit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_24]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)[90:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)[55:org.springframework.aop:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy1044.findForEdit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_24]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation.invoke(BeanInvocation.java:83)[120:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.1]
    ... 46 more
2012-11-05 10:44:35,335 | WARN  | org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger | Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [our.own.SomethingException: Some explanation of exception here]
```

Now, what might be complicating these here is the 'path' that this method call takes.

The client uses a JMS Request-Reply message to call the server using the following route definiition:

```
<bean id="animalTypeDataManager" class="org.apache.camel.spring.remoting.CamelProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="jms:animalTypeDataManager"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="uniworks.ServiceManagers.a.Animal.AnimalTypeDataInterface"/>
</bean>
```

The server end of that route is defined in one OSGi bundle (lets call 'BundleA') as follows:

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="jms:animalTypeDataManager"/>
    <camel:to uri="bean:osgi_animalTypeDataManager"/>
</camel:route>
```

The bean referred to in this route is actually in another bundle ('BundleB') as an OSGi 'service'. BundleA has reference to this bean defined as follows:

```
<reference id="osgi_animalTypeDataManager" 
           interface="uniworks.ServiceManagers.a.Animal.AnimalTypeDataInterface"/>
```

And BundleB has the service defined as follows:

```
<service id="osgi_animalTypeDataManager" ref="animalTypeDataManager" 
         interface="uniworks.ServiceManagers.a.Animal.AnimalTypeDataInterface"/>
```

It is this final service bean that is throwing the Exception.

I could put an `errorHandler` on each of the server ends of these routes (in BundleA), but I'd like to be able to do this generically in one place.

I tried defining a logging error handler (as per the [Camel Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html)) in BundleA as follows:

```
<camel:errorHandler id="loggingErrorHandler" type="LoggingErrorHandler" logName="mylogger.name" level="DEBUG"/>

<camel:camelContext id="bundleA_camel" errorHandlerRef="loggingErrorHandler">

..... [jms routes defined in here]

</camel:context>
```

But that did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Can you provide more info, like your route, error handler etc.?

Comment: @Petter, see my edit above. There is currently no errorHandler defined (apart from the attempt I described above) so it should be using the default errorHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after Claus's hints, and the section of the Camel Docs [here](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html#ErrorHandler-Springbasedconfiguration), I finally managed to get rid of the stack-trace.

Before the Spring DSL definition of the Camel context that contains the routes that take JMS messages and pass them onto the `bean` references, I defined an instance of a `noErrorHandler` as follows:

```
<camel:errorHandler id="noErrorHandler" type="NoErrorHandler"/>
```

Then, I added that error handler to the Camel context itself, thus:

```
<camel:camelContext id="bundle_camel" errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">
```

Now, any exceptions thrown by the beans will propogate back to the caller without Camel logging the stack-trace.

Answer (score 4):

The 1st log with the stacktrace is from Camel's error handler which by default log exhausted failures at ERROR level with stacktrace. You can configure this to your likings. See details at Camel's error handler docs.
http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html

The 2nd log is from the JmsConsumer and the option errorHandlerLogStackTrace=false, ought to force it to not log the stack trace. I am not sure if Camel 2.9.1 has a bug in this area. I tried on latest Camel and it works fine there.

Here is an unit test which may help you
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?rev=1405307&view=rev

Comment: you gave me a few more pointers as to what to look for, and I have made some progress (see edit of my question), but I have only managed to get rid of one of the stack-traces.

Comment: Can you try specifying errorHandlerRef on each <route> as well. The was a bug once, in XML DSL where the errorHandlerRef on <camelContext> didn't work properly.

Comment: where does the reference go? On the `<camel:route>` or on the `<camel:to uri="bean:.....">`? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I defined the `loggingErrorHandler` as above _outside_ the camel context, and on the route defined inside the context that has the affected bean as the `to` endpoint, I added the `errorHandlerRef="loggingErrorHandler"` property, and the stack trace still appears in the log.

Comment: Is there a way to use `doTry ... doCatch` around all the route definitions that will allowed the Exception to propagate back to the client, but just not log the stack trace?

Comment: Its on the <route>'s not on the <to>'s.

Comment: Nope, I added the reference to the `loggingErrorHandler` on the <route> as stated above and it has made no difference to the stack-trace output. I guess I may have to define my own error handler, but what should it do with the error. Can you point me to some example code for such an errorHandler?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **logExhausted(false)**

```
onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .logExhausted(false)
```

Comment: This prevented the longer of the two stack traces I'm getting with errors, thanks!